# Резиновый дизайн

Tags: html, css, javascript

Здравствуйте. Вопрос такой: есть дивный блок с контентом, нужно сделать так чтоб этот блок подстраивался высотой не под длину контента, а под разрешение любого экрана. Как это реализовать??

Comment: min-height: 100%;

Answer (score 2):

Главное правило для соблюдения 100% высоты: "все родительские и нужный вам элемент, должны иметь ***height: 100%***"

Что-то типа этого:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>HEIGHT == 100%</title>
      <style type="text/css">
          html, body, #wrap { height:100%; }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="wrap">
       </div>
    <body>
  <html>
```

Comment: к сожалению не помогло, высота контента по прежнему меняется в зависимости от самого контента, а мне нужно чтоб высота блока с  контенто приклеивалась, подстраивалась именно под границы монитора!

Comment: Просто помимо процентов надо еще помнить о переполнение overflow:
http://jsfiddle.net/5EFa3/

Comment: @kiberchainik, поделитесь кодом, хотя бы скелетом вашей структуры, - подправим )

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<header class="header">
</header>
<div class="middle"> <!-- задача: блок мидл и все что в нем внутри автоматически подстраивало высоту под расширение экрана -->
<aside class="left-sidebar">
</aside> 
<div class="container">
<main class="content"> <!-- если контент длинный тогда прокрутка автоматически появиться у этого блока -->
<div>тут может быть все что угодно и не важно какой длины</div>
</main><!-- .content -->
</div><!-- .container-->
</div><!-- .middle-->
</div><!-- .wrapper -->
<footer class="footer">
</footer>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @kiberchainik, Что бы растянуть именно **div** в классе **content** добавьте этот **css**:  

    html, body, .wrapper, .middle, .container, .content, .content div{ height: 100%; }
    .content div{ margin: 0 auto; width: 800px; border-left: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black; background: #eaeaea; }  

Но, по моему, Вы слишком много лишних блоков понасоздавали )  
И Я бы растянул внешний блок на всю высоту, допустим **.wrapper**, а в нем бы работал с другими элементами (они ж все с прозрачным фоном).

Comment: ставлю то что Вы посоветовали блок контента падает вниз ровно на 100% расширения экрана ))  вот сайт demo.axelcom.ws

Comment: @kiberchainik, Прикрепите, тот CSS, что я Вам дал, к тому "скелету" основы вашего сайта, что дали Вы мне - всё отлично растянется.

А налепить сначала кучу стилей и скриптов, а потом искать решение в самом корне - явно не верный подход.

Comment: я согласен с замечанием, НО! как в моем так и Вашем не правильно ведут себя header и footer. сделайте в своем примере их фиксированными а блок контента резиновым, чтоб подстраивался под все или многие расширения кранов!

Comment: @kiberchainik,  
Кароче!) Насчет проблем структуры вашего сайта (demo.axelcom.ws)!
  
Главная проблема в том, что у Вас у **left-sidebar**, стоит **min-height:100%**!  

Итак, план действий:  
- добавьте во всю основную иерархическую цепочку **height 100%**;  
- у **left-sidebar**, **min-height: 100%** - забрать!  
- что бы убрать скролл (справа, от контента) добавьте в **container** стиль **overflow: visible**;  
- а футер, поднялся из-за постоянных отступов! Так что Вам надо либо пересмотреть свой подход к верстке, либо опустить этот футер на нужное количество пикселей (110+)